# access button's properties in User Control wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have a Custom UserControl . In that UserControl i have some buttons , comboboxes , textboxses. When  i use it in wpf application i want to be able to change button's background and size... I have names for all the controls , but when i try to access them in wpf Application , i even cannot see them.

here is the user control -

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl.UserControl"
         Name="MyCustomUSerControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="620" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="LavenderBlush" x:Name="Grid_MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Header="Filter" FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT">
        <Border CornerRadius="12" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" x:Name="StackPanel_ManinStackInExpander" >
                <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel_Column" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,10">
                    <Label x:Name="Label_Column" Content="Column" Height="22" Width="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Rockwell" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Columns" Background="Transparent" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" FontFamily="Bernard MT"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Label_Like" Content="Like" Height="22" Width="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Rockwell" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                    <TextBox Background="Transparent" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Bernard MT" MinWidth="100" x:Name="TextBox_Like"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label x:Name="Label_Operation" Content="Operation" FontFamily="Rockwell"/>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Operation" Background="Transparent" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="&lt;"> </ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content=">"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="="></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content=">="></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="&lt;="></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="&lt;>"></ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <Label Content="Value" x:Name="Label_Value" FontFamily="Rockwell"/>
                            <TextBox Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,10">
                    <Button x:Name="Button_AND" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Content="AND" Height="20" Width="70" Margin="10" FontFamily="Californian FB" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Button_OR" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Content="OR" Height="20" Width="70" Margin="10,0,10,10" FontFamily="Californian FB" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListView Margin="10" MinWidth="200" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1"></ListView>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,10,10,10">
                    <Button x:Name="Button_Enclose" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Width="120" Height="25" Margin="10" Content="(  )" FontFamily="Californian FB" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Button_Filter" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Width="120" Height="25" Margin="10,45,10,0" Content="FIlter" FontFamily="Californian FB" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </Border>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using C# add x:FieldModifier="public" to the elements you want to expose.

[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx)